# Selenium webdriver timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium.WebDriver with C# (NET 5.0) and sometimes and **only sometimes**, i get this exception due a timeout:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63127/session/32e3a5ce458f1cc856653180a734b3dc/window timed out after 60 seconds.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Close()
   at ServicioScraper.Controllers.RCVController.GetVentasAsync(Int32 mes, Int32 anio, BasicData input) in C:\Users\Gonzalo Bustamante\source\repos\chilesystems\ServicioScraper\Controllers\RCVController.cs:line 252
```

In RCVController, line 252:

```
if (driver != null)
{
   driver.Close();  <--- here
   driver.Quit();
}
```

This exception is only throwed when the app tries to launch chromedriver, not after.

This is how the instance of driver is created:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(downloadFolder));
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", true);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Performance, LogLevel.All);
options.LeaveBrowserRunning = false;
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I cant get this error on Development, only on Production.

Production Server:
Windows Server 2016
Internet Information Services
ChromeDriver version: 103 (latest until now)

Thanks!

Comment: avoid using close() method.  Quit() should close the browser and dispose of the driver instance.  (only use close() to close a 2nd or 3rd window/tab...)  It used to be that close() would close the current tab/window and then dispose of the driver if that was the last window open.  I think post v99 it became a little buggy and could cause orphaned driver processes to remain open.   If you keep seeing these errors you can try increasing the command timeout when launching the grid.  (I think there's a launch flag for that...)

Comment: i tried this and the problem persist. the timeout is launched even when is the fist call

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this, Gonzalo?